# Flex / LCDS : Serializing InputStream as ByteArray using BeanProxy

Tags: java, apache-flex, lcds

I'm trying to serialize an object which has an InputStream.  I need it to arrive on the flex client as a ByteArray.

Note - I can't implement `IExternalizable` on this class, as it's not mine.

I've registered a custom `BeanProxy` to do the conversion, however it doesn't appear to be working:

```
public class InputStreamBeanProxy extends BeanProxy {
    @Override
    public Object getInstanceToSerialize(Object instance) {

        InputStream stream = (InputStream) instance;
        Byte[] boxOfBytes;
            try {
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
                boxOfBytes = new Byte[bytes.length];
                for (int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++)
                {
                   boxOfBytes[i] = bytes[i];
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Exception serializing inputStream: ", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return boxOfBytes;
       }
}
```

This proxy is then registered during startup as follows:

```
PropertyProxyRegistry.getRegistry().register(InputStream.class, new InputStreamBeanProxy());
```

I've set breakpoints in this code, and I see it being called as expected.  However when the object arrives on the client, the input stream is typed as `Object`, and it contains no properties.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - solved this.

The problem is that when proxying an object, the value returned by `getInstanceToSerialize` is then serialized based on it's individual properties - ie serialized as an object.

You cannot return a "primitive" type here (to quote the javadocs).  By primitive, they refer to primtiive flashplayer types.  Since I wanted `byte[]` to arrive as a `ByteArray` - which is a primitive type, my original approach doesn't work.

Instead, the solution was to proxy the property of the owning class, rather than the InputStream directly.

Here's the working proxy:

```
public class InputStreamBeanProxy extends BeanProxy {

    @Override
    public Object getValue(Object instance, String propertyName) {
        Object value = super.getValue(instance, propertyName);
        if (value instanceof InputStream) {
            value = getByteArray((InputStream) value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private byte[] getByteArray(InputStream stream) {

        try {
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
            return bytes;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception serializing inputStream: ", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Assuming I was trying to serialize the following class:

```
public class MyThing
{
     InputStream myStream;
     ...
 }
```

This would be registered as follows:

```
PropertyProxyRegistry.getRegistry().register(MyThing.class, new InputStreamBeanProxy());
```